# Reference a cell's number in a function on a macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Creating a macro function to input a function on multiple cells.
A range in the function depends on the value of another cell.

The function is =INDEX($B$3:$B$***,RANK(C5,$C$3:$C$***,1))

The three * represent where I must input the value of cell G2, currently, G2 value is 12 so the function should read 
            =INDEX($B$3:$B$12,RANK(C5,$C$3:$C$12,1))
The function in G2 is =LOOKUP(2,1/(B:B<>""),ROW(B:B))

I have tried with Activecell.Value and Activecell.formular1c1
but so far no luck.

I tried the following code but it isn't really a function.

```
Range("D3").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "=INDEX($B$3:B$"
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & R2C7
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & "C5,RANK(C5,$C$3:$C$"
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & R2C7
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & ",1))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concatenate the value in, and use `Range.Formula`

Something like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim x
    x = Range("G2").Value
    Range("D3").Formula = "=INDEX($B$3:$B$" & x & ",RANK(C5,$C$3:$C$" & x & ",1))"
End Sub
```

If you're just looking for the last row, then perhaps:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Range("D3").Formula = "=INDEX($B$3:$B$" & lastRow & ",RANK(C5,$C$3:$C$" & lastRow & ",1))"
End Sub
```